# How to use UPPER keyword with the INNER JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query in which I want to use INNER JOIN with the UPPER keyword.

**=>** *CASE A with INNER JOIN*: I am doing INNER JOIN with the other table. Notice I have not written the complete query so you won't find `INNER JOIN` keyword below.

**=>** *CASE B without INNER JOIN*: I am not doing INNER JOIN with the other table. Notice I have not written the complete query.

**1st query**:

*Case A with INNER JOIN*: `UPPER(hello_world.column_name1) AS COLUMN_NAME1,`

*CASE B without INNER JOIN:* `UPPER(column_name1) AS COLUMN_NAME1,`

**2nd query**:

*CASE A with INNER JOIN*: `UPPER(CASE WHEN hello_world.COLUMN_NAME2 IS NULL THEN 'Open' ELSE hello_world.COLUMN_NAME2 END) AS COLUMN_NAME2,`

*CASE B without INNER JOIN:* `UPPER(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME2 IS NULL THEN 'Open' ELSE COLUMN_NAME2 END) AS COLUMN_NAME2,`

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if its the right way to use `INNER JOIN with the UPPER keyword (CASE A in both queries)`.

Comment: An inner join requires a predicate, as in `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b ON <predicate>`. Any predicate (expression that evaluates to a boolean) will work.

Answer (score 0):

If it yields the results you expect, then yes. `INNER JOIN` is the act of joining two tables, that is, based on a criteria, records from table1 will be matched by records from table2 as long as they meet the criteria and such matches will yield records of table3, i.e. the result.

Your criteria needs to be boolean, that is, it can be true and it can be false. In the formula of your criteria you may use the `UPPER` function, like

```
...
FROM A
JOIN B
ON UPPER(A.X) = UPPER(B.Y)
...
```

Yet, your `UPPER(hello_world.column_name1) AS COLUMN_NAME1` strongly suggests that you ponder about the `SELECT` clause of a query, which, based on your description has a join. The use of `UPPER` is useful wherever it makes sense and it is syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation. Completely make sense what you have said. I've not written the complete query above. I have added few more lines to make more sense. Just wondering 
if my usage of UPPER keyword is correct with the SELECT keyword.

Comment: `SELECT UPPER(hello_world.column_name1) AS COLUMN_NAME1,
        UPPER(CASE WHEN hello_world.COLUMN_NAME2 IS NULL THEN 'Open' ELSE hello_world.COLUMN_NAME2 END) AS COLUMN_NAME2
    FROM
        hello_world INNER JOIN good_morning
    ON  hello_world.ab_cd = good_morning.ab_cd
    ORDER BY
        ab_cd ASC`

Comment: @flash if this consistently yields the result you expect, then yes. But, let me observe that your case-when inside the second `UPPER` has an `ELSE`, evaluating to `hello_world.COLUMN_NAME2` which is `NULL` in that case. Since the `ELSE` defaults to `NULL`, you do not need the `ELSE` at all in this case, but that's not a logical error, just an overcomplication.